# Philosophic current in this excerpt of Ask the dust

Tags: knowledge, existence

I read *Ask the dust* by John Fante. The following is an excerpt from the book. It is right after Arturo went to Vera Rivken's place and feels guilty for having slept with her.

My question is: what is the philosophical current that can describe the sentences in bold? That is: if I can see or feel some thing, I believe it exists. Otherwise I cannot be sure, even up to denying the whole existence of that thing.

> At the end of the row of concessions the sand beach began. Beyond were
> dunes. I waded through the sand to a place where the dunes hid the
> boardwalk. This needed thinking out. I didn’t kneel; I sat down and
> watched the breakers eating the shore. This is bad, Arturo. You have
> read Nietzsche, you have read Voltaire, you should know better. But
> reasoning wouldn’t help. I could reason myself out of it, but that was
> not my blood. It was my blood that kept me alive, it was my blood
> pouring through me, telling me it was wrong. I sat there and gave
> myself over to my blood, let it carry me swimming back to the deep sea
> of my beginnings. Vera Rivken, Arturo Bandini. It was not meant that
> way: it was never meant that way. I was wrong. I had committed a
> mortal sin. I could figure it mathematically, philosophically,
> psychologically: I could prove it a dozen ways, but I was wrong, for
> there was no denying the warm even rhythm of my guilt.
>
> Sick in my soul I tried to face the ordeal of seeking forgiveness. From whom? What
> God, what Christ? They were myths I once believed, and now they were
> beliefs I felt were myths. **This is the sea, and this is Arturo, and
> the sea is real, and Arturo believes it real. Then I turn from the
> sea, and everywhere I look there is land; I walk on and on, and still
> the land goes stretching away to the horizons. A year, five years, ten
> years, and I have not seen the sea. I say unto myself, but what has
> happened to the sea? And I answer, the sea is back there, back in the
> reservoir of memory. The sea is a myth. There never was a sea.** But
> there was a sea! I tell you I was born on the seashore! I bathed in
> the waters of the sea! It gave me food and it gave me peace, and its
> fascinating distances fed my dreams! **No Arturo, there never was a sea.
> You dream and you wish, but you go on through the wasteland. You will
> never see the sea again. It was a myth you once believed.** But, I have
> to smile, for the salt of the sea is in my blood, and there may be ten
> thousand roads over the land, but they shall never confuse me, for my
> heart’s blood will ever return to its beautiful source.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Could you tell us where the question came from? Is there any particular reason to believe that this particular passage describes any particular philosophical current? It sounds pretty poetically vague, could be some sort of positivism or pragmatism or materialism, but any of it is a stretch.

Comment: ...the *salt* of the sea is *in my blood*...and my heart’s blood will ever return to its beautiful *source*...Intuitively the sea exists, because he's *related* to it by blood. Even when he can't experience it directly as 'another', he experiences it as a part of himself. Ashes to ashes, dust to dust... *And the Lord God formed man of the* ***dust*** *of the ground...*